# Oracle APEX - Setting up a Tabular Form with default values

Tags: oracle-apex, tabular-form

I pretty new to APEX and I'm having a bit of trouble working with my first Tabular form.  The table I've linked it to is fairly simple.  The columns are as follows:

- Primary key representing an internal
  code for a college major
- Foreign key representing the "real"
  code for the college major
- Description for the college major
- The user that inserted/updated the
  row in the table
- The date the row was inserted/updated

At the moment, I'm facing two problems.

1. I want the user to be able to specify their own primary key for the row but not to be able to change any existing primary keys.  When I specify the column type as "Text Field" users are able to edit existing rows' primary keys and it also seems to break the report when trying to add a new row as I get a checksum error.
2. <strike>I would like the user and date
   columns to default to the currently
   logged in user and the current date,
   but specifying default values for
   either of these columns also seems
   to cause syntax/SQL errors.  Does
   anyone have any examples of how to
   use the default value functionality
   for a column?</strike>  Fixed.  I can just use SYSDATE as a value on it's own when specifying the PL/SQL type for default.  Username can be obtained through functions in APEX_UTIL

Comment: Is the checksum error because you have turned on checksums for the page?  Or does the error come from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use 2 conditional fields. If the field value is null, display the edit box, if the field value is not null display the display-only field.